# Developing auto translation for MFC interfaces

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I developed an application with Visual C + + and MFC, I need to translate the help files (one file per language), I'm looking for a solution similar to i18n in PHP.

When the application is installed on the windows, it is necessary that the application detects the language settings of "Windows" and display the corresponding translation, if the Windows language is not supported, it should set the default language (English).

Answer (score 0):

If you use dialogs, you can create language specific versions of the dialogs.  For normal strings you can use language specific string table resources.

If you need more direct control you can use the various [national language support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) apis.

Comment: Is there a similar method i18n in PHP?

Comment: If you can find a separate library, perhaps. From a quick google search, i18n libraries for c++ are mostly targeted at linux compilers.